# Timthumb and tmp folder

Tags: linux, wordpress, image-resizing, timthumb

Recently a web space ran out of space. Now I found out that the `tmp` folder outside the home directory was full of these files: `timthumb_tmpimg_00BZyC`. Some of these files can't be opened. Why is `timthumb` storing files outside the home directory? The `tmp` folder is on the same level like `dev`, `etc`, `proc`, `root`, `sys` and so on.

Has the site a security problem? Are some settings incorrect?

Timthumb is used in version 2.8.5 by the Wordpress plugin `vSlider`. The site also uses `Simple Post Thumbnails` which uses Timthumb in v. 2.7. I replaced both with Timthumb 2.8.10.

Or does it have to do with temporary files created by timthumb, which were never deleted?

Answer (score 1):

`/tmp` is intended to be world-writeable -- though if you try the following:

```
ls -l / | grep tmp
```

you'll see that it has the sticky (`t`) bit on, meaning that files created by a user can only be deleted by the same user or a superuser, to prevent different users from clobbering each other's temporary files. This is similar to the `%SYSTEMDIR%\TEMP` directory in Windows.

So it's not a security problem on the Linux side, though it could be a misconfiguration or a bug on the part of the WordPress plugin you're using. Is there an option limiting how many thumbnails it keeps?

Comment: No, I didn't found any options. Now I checked the tmp-folder and it seems that there are only a few files. Perhaps it works now. Let's see.